# Inventory attribute values DAC

Tags: acumatica

What table(s)/DAC(s) are used to hold the attribute values on the Stock Items screen/Attributes tab?  I need to access them in a GI and I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Attributes are stored in CSAnswers. The refNoteID in CSAnswers maps to the NoteID in InventoryItem. Each attribute is listed by the AttributeID, so to join specific attribute(s) you'll need to specify the AttributeID also. [image]